# "The biggest loser...IS personal meetings" or "The biggest loser...ARE personal meetings"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I have a grammar question that I'd like to know the answer to that came up in a discussion. Which of the following two versions of a sentence is correct?

> a) The biggest loser among free-time activities *is* personal meetings.

or

> b) The biggest loser under free-time activities *are* personal meetings.

Comment: The subject of the sentence is _the biggest loser_, which is singular, so...

Comment: Yes, singular "is" is correct, though it does mean that predicative and predicand differ in grammatical number. The OP needs deserves an explanation for this mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

"Is" (to agree with the singular subject "loser")  but **avoid such sentences if possible**. Such sentences can usually be rephrased to avoid the grammar problem.

In this case your sentences are meaningless.  What does it mean for "personal meetings" to be "big losers". It's very unclear. It is easy to rephrase

> Personal meetings are the biggest losers...

But harder to know what you really mean and so hard to know how you should actually express the idea.